# Parent/Child Conversion from Flattened with Mapping Table for Hierarchy Levels

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm attempting to create a hierarchy for each client based on a variety of organizational structures (e.g. Division, Department, Team, Manager, etc..) provided by each client (csv format).  Many of the clients opt for `Division -> Department -> Manager`, but there are some custom scenarios where the client may only want a single level for managers, skip departments and map the managers directly to divisions, or some other combination of the available fields.

To resolve this, I created a self-referencing mapping table (parent/child) to specify each level of the hierarchy. Unfortunately, the code I've put together isn't running very efficiently.  I believe this is due, in part, to duplicate items inside the recursive CTE (see below - parentChildCte).  Is there a more efficient way to obtain a parent/child representation of the Division/Department/Managers? My goal is to be able to take the parent/child output and create nodes using the hierarchyid datatype.

```
use tempdb
go

begin try 

    begin transaction;

    create table Company
    (
        CompanyId int not null,
        Name nvarchar(250) not null,
        constraint pk_Company primary key (CompanyId)
    );

    insert into Company (CompanyId, Name)
    values (1, 'Sample'),
           (2, 'Looney Toons');

    create table Division 
    (
        DivisionId int identity(1,1),
        CompanyId int not null,
        Name nvarchar(250),
        constraint pk_Division primary key (DivisionId),
        constraint fk_Division_Company foreign key (CompanyId) references Company (CompanyId)
    );

    set identity_insert Division on;

    insert into Division (DivisionId, CompanyId, Name)
    values (1, 1, 'Division-Foo'),
           (2, 1, 'Division-Bar'),
           (3, 2, 'Division-Hello'),
           (4, 2, 'Division-World');

    set identity_insert Division off;

    create table Department 
    (
        DepartmentId int identity(1,1),
        CompanyId int not null,
        Name nvarchar(250),
        constraint pk_Department primary key (DepartmentId),
        constraint fk_Department_Company foreign key (CompanyId) references Company (CompanyId)
    );

    set identity_insert Department on;

    insert into Department (DepartmentId, CompanyId, Name)
    values (1, 1, 'Department-One'),
           (2, 1, 'Department-Two'),
           (3, 1, 'Department-Three'),
           (4, 1, 'Department-Four');

    set identity_insert Department off;

    create table Employee 
    (
        EmployeeId int identity(1,1),
        CompanyId int not null,
        FirstName nvarchar(75) not null,
        LastName nvarchar(75) not null,
        DivisionId int null,
        DepartmentId int null,
        ManagerId int null,
        constraint pk_Employee primary key clustered (EmployeeId),
        constraint fk_Employee_Company foreign key (CompanyId) references Company (CompanyId),
        constraint fk_Employee_Division foreign key (DivisionId) references Division (DivisionId),
        constraint fk_Employee_Department foreign key (DepartmentId) references Department (DepartmentId),
        constraint fk_Employee_Manager foreign key (ManagerId) references Employee (EmployeeId)
    );

    set identity_insert Employee on;

    insert into Employee (EmployeeId, CompanyId, FirstName, LastName, DivisionId, DepartmentId, ManagerId)
    values (1, 1, 'John',  'Doe',   1, 2,    null),
           (2, 1, 'Jimmy', 'Smith', 2, 3,    null),
           (3, 1, 'Alice', 'Doe',   2, 3,    2),
           (4, 2, 'Jane',  'Doe',   3, null, null),
           (5, 2, 'Jack',  'Doe',   3, null, 4),
           (6, 2, 'Steve', 'Smith', 4, null, 4),
           (7, 2, 'Jack',  'Doe',   4, null, 4);

    set identity_insert Employee off;

    create table SecurityField
    (
        FieldId int identity(1,1),
        Name nvarchar(25) not null,
        constraint pk_SecurityField primary key (FieldId),
        constraint uq_SecurityFiled_Name unique (Name)
    );

    set identity_insert SecurityField on;

    insert into SecurityField (FieldId, Name)
    values (1, 'Division'),
           (2, 'Department'),
           (3, 'Manager')

    set identity_insert SecurityField off;

    create table SecurityMap
    (   
        MapId int identity(1,1), 
        CompanyId int not null,
        FieldId int not null,
        ParentId int null,   -- Points to the next field up in the hierarchy
        constraint pk_SecurityMap primary key (MapId),
        constraint uq_SecurityMap unique (CompanyId, FieldId, ParentId),
        constraint fk_SecurityMap_Company foreign key (CompanyId) references Company (CompanyId),
        constraint fk_SecurityMap_SecurityMap foreign key (ParentId) references SecurityMap (MapId)
    );

    set identity_insert SecurityMap on;

    insert into SecurityMap (MapId, CompanyId, FieldId, ParentId)
    values (1, 1, 1, null),
           (2, 1, 2, 1),
           (3, 2, 3, null),
           (4, 2, 1, 3)

    set identity_insert SecurityMap off;

    ; with flatCte (CompanyId, DivisionId, Division, DepartmentId, Department, ManagerId, Manager)
    as
    (
        -- Get all unique combinations of Division, Department, and Manager
        select ee.CompanyId,
               div.DivisionId,
               div.Name,
               dept.DepartmentId,
               dept.Name,
               mgr.EmployeeId,
               cast(mgr.FirstName + ' ' + mgr.LastName + ' (' + cast(mgr.EmployeeId as nvarchar(10)) + ')' as nvarchar(250))
        from Employee ee
        left join Division div
            on ee.DivisionId = div.DivisionId
        left join Department dept
            on ee.DepartmentId = dept.DepartmentId
        left join Employee mgr 
            on ee.ManagerId = mgr.EmployeeId
        group by ee.CompanyId,
                 div.DivisionId,
                 div.Name,
                 dept.DepartmentId,
                 dept.Name,
                 mgr.EmployeeId,
                 cast(mgr.FirstName + ' ' + mgr.LastName + ' (' + cast(mgr.EmployeeId as nvarchar(10)) + ')' as nvarchar(250))
    )
    ,parentChildCte (CompanyId, GroupId, GroupName, ParentId, ParentName, FieldId, MapId)
     as
     (
         -- Recusively go through and get the parent/child combinations for the items in flatCte
         select flat.CompanyId,
                case 
                  when map.FieldId = 1 then flat.DivisionId
                  when map.FieldId = 2 then flat.DepartmentId
                  when map.FieldId = 3 then flat.ManagerId
                end,
                case 
                  when map.FieldId = 1 then flat.Division
                  when map.FieldId = 2 then flat.Department
                  when map.FieldId = 3 then flat.Manager
                end,
                cast(null as int),
                cast(null as nvarchar(250)),
                map.FieldId,
                map.MapId
         from flatCte flat
         join SecurityMap map
             on flat.CompanyId = map.CompanyId
         where map.ParentId is null

         union all

         select flat.CompanyId,
                case
                  when map.FieldId = 1 then flat.DivisionId
                  when map.FieldId = 2 then flat.DepartmentId
                  when map.FieldId = 3 then flat.ManagerId
                end,
                case 
                  when map.FieldId = 1 then flat.Division
                  when map.FieldId = 2 then flat.Department
                  when map.FieldId = 3 then flat.Manager
                end,
                cte.GroupId, 
                cte.GroupName,           
                map.FieldId,
                map.MapId
         from flatCte flat
         join SecurityMap map    
             on flat.CompanyId = map.CompanyId
         join parentChildCte cte 
             on map.ParentId = cte.MapId
                 and cte.Groupid = case
                                     when cte.FieldId = 1 then flat.DivisionId
                                     when cte.FieldId = 2 then flat.DepartmentId
                                     when cte.FieldId = 3 then flat.ManagerId
                                   end
     )  

    select CompanyId,
             ParentId, 
             ParentName,
             GroupId, 
             GroupName
    from parentChildCte 
    where GroupId is not null       
    group by CompanyId,
             ParentId, 
             ParentName,
             GroupId, 
             GroupName
    order by CompanyId, 
             ParentName, 
             GroupName


    commit transaction
end try
begin catch
    if @@trancount > 0 begin
        rollback;
    end;
    throw;
end catch
```

Comment: I would skip the `HierarchyId` and use a Kimball Helper/Bridge Table [Louis Davidson - Presentations - How to Optimize a Hierarchy In SQL Server - Presentations & Demo Code](http://www.drsql.org/Pages/Presentations.aspx)

Comment: I asked a similar question time ago, maybe can help you: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/160924/can-i-get-a-tree-structure-from-a-self-referenced-hierarchical-table

Comment: You'd certainly make your life easier if all the data were in one table (instead of scattered among many) . You could do this, for example, by adding a `Type` column that encodes whether that row represents a Division, Manager, etc. I know it's not the data structure you have, but trying to wrap my head around what you've got going on now is giving me a headache.